# PHP keep printed/echoed values after submitting

Tags: php, echo

This is a simplified version of the code I currently have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form" action="" method="post">
            <input name="button1" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['button1'])){ 
        echo 'Test';
    }
?>
```

and this code outputs `Test` when I click the button once, but when I click it another time, it clears the first echo, and reprints it, so the output will still be one `Test`. Is there any way in PHP to stop it from clearing the first echo so the output would become `TestTest`?

Comment: @apokryfos is this the way to go? I am fairly new to PHP and I thought there would be a function for this?

Comment: Without persisting the output between the requests, no there isn't.... by default, PHP executes and terminates with each request, unless you specifically persist information between requests (session, database, cache store, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web is stateless. Each time you click submit you start a new request which (as far as the server is concerned) is coming from a brand new user. The web server can't remember (or doesn't care) that you just made a request earlier. The act of clicking on the submit button creates a new request and loads the page from scratch.

PHP has a way around this by using sessions to maintain state information. A session is PHPs way of saying "hey I know who this person is, I've seen them before".

You can use the session to do this in the following way.

```
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form" action="" method="post">
            <input name="button1" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['button1'])){ 
        $_SESSION["counter"] = (isset($_SESSION["counter"])?$_SESSION["counter"]:0) + 1;
        for ($i = 0;$i < $_SESSION["counter"];$i++) 
            echo 'Test';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Had a feeling you'd put an answer in. When I noticed you deleted your comment to suggest to use sessions, my "Spidey sense" had a wee bit of a tingle *lol* Edit: Might want to give them the option to eventually destroy the session also as a reset.

Comment: @apokryfos beat me to it. I posted an almost dupplicate answer :)

Comment: This answer should be accepted since it gives a better explanation than mine

Answer (score 2):

you could set a [session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

```
<?php 

session_start();

        if (isset($_POST['button1'])){ 
            if(isset($_SESSION['myvar'])){
                $_SESSION['myvar'] .= 'Test';
            }else {
                $_SESSION['myvar'] = 'Test';
            }
            echo $_SESSION['myvar'];
        }
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form" action="" method="post">
            <input name="button1" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <hr>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have not tested this code but it should work

NOTE: you may to trap potential errors if your session is not started
this may answer your original question, however there may be better solutions depending what your end goal is.

make sure to include the above php code above the html markup
EDITED: incorporated Fred sugestions

Comment: Might want to get rid of the leading spaces before the opening php tag; that might throw a headers sent notice.

Comment: You also need to fix your answer, since that will throw a `Notice: Undefined index: myvar in...` on first click.